# Directx9 - Generate mesh from vertex and index buffer

Tags: directx9

I've got a single vertex buffer and an index buffer for a cube in Directx9. I now want to generate a LPD3DXMESH  object from them, so that I can manage mouse picking and other stuff with the cube model. How can I achieve this? Here's the code of my vertex and index buffers:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
{
    { -3﻿.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { 3.0f,﻿ 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
    { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), },
};

d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(8 * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                           0,
                           CUSTOMFVF,
                           D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                           &vertex_buffer,
                           NULL);

VOID* pVoid;
vertex_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
vertex_buffer->Unlock();

short indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3,
    4, 0, 6,
    6, 0, 2,﻿
    7, 5, 6,
    6, 5, 4,
    3, 1, 7,
    7, 1, 5,
    4, 5, 0,
    0, 5, 1,
    3, 7, 2,
    2, 7, 6,
};

d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(36 * sizeof(short),
                          0,
                          D3DFMT_INDEX16,
                          D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                          &index_buffer,
                   ﻿       NULL);

index_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
memcpy(pVoid, indices, ﻿sizeof(indices));
index_buffer->Unlock();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as far as I recall, create a mesh directly from vertex or index buffers (as the mesh object wants to maintain those buffers itself). You can create it from the vertex and index data you already have though:

1. Create the mesh using [`D3DXCreateMeshFVF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3dxcreatemeshfvf), providing the appropriate vertex format information and the correct face and index counts.
2. Use `LockVertexBuffer` and `LockIndexBuffer` on the resulting mesh (they are both [base class methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/id3dxbasemesh)) to get pointers to the buffer content.
3. Copy your data into the resulting pointers.
4. Unlock the buffers.

With this method you don't need to call `CreateVertexBuffer` or `CreateIndexBuffer` yourself, as the mesh will do so. Make sure you pass the correct [flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/d3dxmesh) to the mesh-creation function to ensure the underlying buffers are created in the (managed) pool you expect them to be in.